# How to store jQuery roundslider value in a variable

Tags: jquery

I need to store the jQuery roundSlider value in a variable. The slider options look like this:

```
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    radius: 125,
    value: 0,
    circleShape: "pie",
    startAngle: 315,
    width: 12,
    handleSize: "+10",
    mouseScrollAction: true,
    editableTooltip: false,
    tooltipFormat: function (e) {
      let val = e.value;
      return `
      <div class="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/img/brightness-control.png" alt="Brightness control icon"> ${val + "%"}
        <span class="slider-text">Brightness</span>
       </div>`;
  }
});
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the value of the slider:

```
var testvalue = $("#slider").roundSlider("getValue")
console.log(testvalue);
```

However this doesn't work, it just shows the initial value which is 0, but it won't change the value state. Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've also wrapped it inside an event, the code you posted to get the value is only running at the very beginning (when it's first created), thus the value will always be 0.

See below, where I've attached a click event to a button, to report the value.

**EDIT:** 
I've assigned the roundSlider object to the variable `slider`. Now it can be called anytime with `slider.roundSlider("getValue").

The problem (with what you want to achieve), is that there is no variable with that value stored. `roundSlider("getValue");` is calling a function inside the roundSlider object; `"getValue"` is an argument, telling that function to `return value;`. Thus there is nothing for you to actually get a shallow copy of, to get a dynamic value; you must use the `roundSlider();` function, and pass in `"getValue"` or `"setValue"` string - as an argument - to have it return the value.

The `roundSlider` object doesn't even appear to store the number - it calculates the number on the fly, does its magic, then "turns off". The only way for "automating" this behaviour, can be seen in my second snippet.

```js
var slider = $("#slider").roundSlider({
  sliderType: "min-range",
  radius: 125,
  value: 0,
  circleShape: "pie",
  startAngle: 315,
  width: 12,
  handleSize: "+10",
  mouseScrollAction: true,
  editableTooltip: false,
  tooltipFormat: function(e) {
    let val = e.value;
    return `
      <div class="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/img/brightness-control.png" alt="Brightness control icon"> ${val + "%"}
        <span class="slider-text">Brightness</span>
       </div>`;
  } 
});


$('button#btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log(slider.roundSlider("getValue"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

<button id="btn">Value</button>
```

This uses `slider.on('change', () => {...}` to automatically change the variable, every time the slider is affected (which happens on `mouseup`).

```js
var slider = $("#slider").roundSlider({
  sliderType: "min-range",
  radius: 125,
  value: 0,
  circleShape: "pie",
  startAngle: 315,
  width: 12,
  handleSize: "+10",
  mouseScrollAction: true,
  editableTooltip: false,
  tooltipFormat: function(e) {
    let val = e.value;
    return `
      <div class="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/img/brightness-control.png" alt="Brightness control icon"> ${val + "%"}
        <span class="slider-text">Brightness</span>
       </div>`;
  }
});

var sliderValue = slider.roundSlider("getValue");

slider.on('change', () => {
  sliderValue = slider.roundSlider("getValue");
  console.log(sliderValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: I guess I can use this somehow, it's better than what I had. I thought I could store the slider value into a variable without attaching an event (click event in this case)

Comment: @Gilbert Storing the value into a variable, would only store the value at the time you assigned it to the variable. What you could do though, is something like `var mySlider = $('#slider');`, then later call `mySlider.roundSlider('getValue')`

Comment: but that doesn't update the value, when I use `console.log(mySlider.roundSlider('getValue'))` the value remains 0 (which is the original state). I need this value stored in a variable and update accordingly.

Comment: @MatthewMoore correct.. you can use the change event so that you can do your custom logic whenever the user changes the slider value.. if you want to do it in each handle movement then you can use the [drag](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#drag) event also..

Comment: @Soundar That is how I handled updating the variable in the second snippet, using `change`. Although I hadn't noticed the `drag` event.